# Incorrect locale code from Google Chrome on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, locale

On Mac, the operating system language is the chrome browser language. I change the language to English (Canada) but the chrome extension I created was picking up en_US as the locale code. Tried it with multiple mac devices and the behaviors were all similar.

Used this method to get the language:

```
 chrome.i18n.getMessage('@@ui_locale')
```

also tried using

```
 chrome.i18n.getUILanguage()
```

and they both had similar results which is en_US and en-US respectively.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome, see if it's reported on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Thought so as well. Thanks, I couldn't find the exact problem there so I'll just file one myself.